# Is book recommendation or review on-topic on this site?

Tags: discussion

If one asks to recommend a book or asks to review a specific textbook about artificial intelligence, is this considered on-topic for this site?

Comment: Asking for recommendations on specific resources is on-topic and many questions of the sort have been asked before on the site.  I have not seen many reviews of books. Seeing as reviews on single resources are heavily opinion-based (which we try to stay away from on the site), I'd be very hesitant to call it on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

**Reviews are off-topic** because they lead to opinions.

Asking for (examples of) books or research papers on AI topics is on-topic.

However, try to avoid  questions like "What's *the best* book on X?" because that can also lead to opinions. It's better to formulate these questions in a way that answers are not just based on taste but based on facts.